# Problems including two JS scripts in one view using CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have created default view template

```
<html>
        <head>
                <?=$head?>
        </head>
        <body>
                <?=$navmenu?>

        </body>
</html>
```

where after navmenu I can write whatever html or echo data from controller. In my controller it looks like this:

```
$data['head'] = $this->load->view('templates/head', NULL, TRUE);
$data['navmenu'] = $this->load->view('templates/navmenu', NULL, TRUE);
$this->load->view('products/create', $data);
```

In this way I can easly change head or navmenu in every page of my site. Problem starts in navmenu. Here is the code:

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='/test4/index.php/Pages/view'>home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login-link" id="login-link">login</a></li>
        <li><a href='/test4/index.php/Pages/view/about'>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href='/test4/index.php/Pages/view/faq'>FAq</a></li>
        <li><a href='/test4/index.php/Pages/view/contact'>Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href='/test4/index.php/products/create'>Create</a></li>
        <li><a href='/test4/index.php/map'>Map</a></li>
        <li><a href='/test4/index.php/auth/logout'>logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<div class="loginpop pop">
    <div id="login-div"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });    
}

$(function() {
  $('#login-link').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));               
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($('#login-link'));
    return false;
  });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};

$('#login-link').click(function(){
        $.get('../auth/login', function(response){
            $('#login-div').html(response);
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

What I have there is pop up window that shows up when "login" is clicked and content of that window I get from AJAX call for another controller(auth/login method). And it works great with one exception - if there is another JS script used in view the login-div is empty.

Here is full view file that does not work correctly:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
<?=$head?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=myApiKey"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>scripts/gmaps.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #map {
      width: 700px;
      height: 700px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?=$navmenu?>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var products = <?= json_encode($products);?>;
    var allMap;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var allMap = new GMaps({
          el: '#map',
          zoom: 7,
          lat: 37.4419,
          lng: -122.1419
        });
        loadJsonMap(allMap, products);
    });

    function loadJsonMap(map, data){
            var markers_data = [];
            $.each(data, function(key, val){
                        if (val.latitude != undefined && val.longitude != undefined) {
                            markers_data.push({
                                lat : val.latitude,
                                lng : val.longitude,
                                details : {
                                    id : val.holder_id
                                },
                                click : function(e){
                                    if(e.details.id !== undefined){
                                        var url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/products/colorbox/' + e.details.id;
                                        $.colorbox({
                                            open : true,
                                            href : url,
                                            iframe : false,
                                            innerWidth : 400,
                                            innerHeight : 400,
                                            close : 'Aizvert'
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
            map.addMarkers(markers_data);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However in this case login-div is not empty:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <?=$head?>
        </head>
        <body>
                <?=$navmenu?>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('products/create'); ?>

    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

    <br /><br />
...(no script here, just html and php echo)
    </body>
</html>
```

Edited: 
I added code for my head as well:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```